# DLL Works with tlbimp, but not regsvr32.exe

Tags: c#, c++, com, mfc, win-universal-app

I have a .dll that was made with MFC in a static library (C++). I am trying to use it in a Universal app(C#). I was unable to reference the .dll in my universal app because I get the error: "Could not resolve COM Reference. The type library importer encountered an error during type verification."

I went to the solution here:
[The type library importer encountered an error during type verification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1680882/the-type-library-importer-encountered-an-error-during-type-verification)
And use tlbimp on my .dll. It successfully pops out a new .dll, but gives a warning: "Importing a type library into a platform agnostic assembly. This can cause errors if the type library is not truly agnostic"

NOTE: The original .dll is 3,000 kb and the tlbimp .dll is only 13 KB. I suspect I am losing the MFC part and probably more.

The new .dll is able to be referenced from my Universal App and I am able to use objects and functions from it. The program successfully compiles, but when I run the program, I get the runtime error: 
"Creating an instance of the COM component with CLSID using CoCreateInstanceFromApp failed due to the following error: 80040154 Class not registered" when I declare an object from the .dll.

NOTE: The call is IHdevice device=new Hdevice(); where IHdevice is an interface and Hdevice is the coclass

I suspected the tlb library was never registered, so I try to register with regsvr32, but when I do I get the error:

"the module Lib.dll was loaded but the entry-point DllRegisterServer was not found"

I know for sure the original .dll has a DllRegisterServer function and is also defined in a .def file. But I assume it is lost when I use tlbimp. Is there a way to register and tlbimp at the same time? Is there any other suggestions you can offer?

Thanks in advance!

UPDATE: I have tried to use regsvr32 on the original .dll and it says "the module failed to load." I have found
http://csi-windows.com/blog/all/73-windows-64-bit/378-fixing-qregsvr32-the-module-failed-to-load-the-specified-module-could-not-be-foundq 
which seems like the same problem, but I have done everything in the solution. I tried putting the dll in SysWOW64 and then trying. I tried putting the dll in System32 and then trying. I tried moving regsvr32 into the same directory and trying. Everytime it cannot find the .dll.

I question: Does the .dll have to be COM visible for this to work. I don't believe anywhere I made the .dll COM visible, and I can't because I would need to have /clr which is incompatible with MFC static.

UPDATE2:
I thought maybe the problem had to do with Universal Apps, so I made a console application, and made the same call. This time the error is: "Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID failed due to the following error: 8007007e The specified module could not be found."

DONT DO THIS: HANS SAYS IT KILLS REGISTRATION!
UPDATE3:
I successfully used RegAsm on the tlbimp .dll (and it says "types registered successfully"). However, I still receive the same error at runtime: Creating an instance...failed due to..Class not registered.

Comment: I think you need to register the original dll. The file that was outputted by TlbImp is just a wrapper, I think.

Comment: You need to stop trying, it isn't going to work.  Universal apps run in a sandbox, only servers found in the package manifest are considered.  All pretty intentional, slate and phone users don't stand a chance solving DLL Hell problems.  The kind of problem you demonstrate so well, UPDATE3 destroyed the registration, you'll have to reinstall it.  Maybe a C++/CX wrapper can still make the code useful, depends.

Comment: @HansPassant you're probably right. But let's say I just want to use it in a simple console program -Update 2- What is happening? Why can't it find the module. I run the program everyday on Windows 7 and it works, I rebuilt with Windows 10 SDK.

Comment: @HansPassant My goal is integrating universal apps with universal drivers. How else would you go about this? The only other idea I have is writing the whole thing in c++

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The .dll was dependent on other .dlls, so when it told me the module was missing, it really meant a different module was missing (the one that my .dll relied on).